# How to put bootstrap tooltip over SVG elements in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, svg

I want try to put bootstrap tooltip over svg element in angularjs, I am not using d3.js, I simply using angularjs. If you give explanation with example that would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is just to append it to the body instead of the parent element.

I created [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HeELyblHZItZPUpCV8dE?p=preview) an example with [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip) angular directives.

```
<svg>
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" tooltip="Hello world" 
        tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement="right"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've added wrong link accidentally, now it's updated. 
Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -1):

As AngularJS is deprecated, this is how is done in Angular using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io):

```
<svg>
<circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" tooltip="Hello world" container="body" placement="right"/>
</svg>
```

[Reference](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples#container)