# How to get a tooltip over an svg circle using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, svg, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am building a page where i am plotting some circles using simple AngularJS and svg. I want a tooltip to be shown when user hovers mouse over the circle. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537014/how-to-put-bootstrap-tooltip-over-svg-elements-in-angularjs) how to do this but its not working for me. Here is my code:

```
<circle ng-repeat="node in slowQueriesCtrl.nodes"
              ng-attr-cx="{{node.x}}"
              ng-attr-cy="{{node.y}}"
              ng-attr-r= "{{node.r}}"
              tooltip="Hello World"
              tooltip-append-to-body="true"
              tooltip-placement="right"
              stroke="green"
              stroke-width="3"
              fill="green">
</circle>
```

I can see my circles showing up in the UI but no tooltip. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since version 0.14.0, all parent directives get the `uib-` prefixes to their names, so the directive's name should be `uib-tooltip` rather than `tooltip`.
2. As @ciril sebastian, noticed, you forget to wrap your `circle` element with the `svg` element.

   ```
   <svg>
       <circle ng-repeat="node in slowQueriesCtrl.nodes"
           ng-attr-cx="{{node.x}}"
           ng-attr-cy="{{node.y}}"
           ng-attr-r= "{{node.r}}"
           uib-tooltip="Hello World"
           tooltip-append-to-body="true"
           tooltip-placement="right"
           stroke="green"
           stroke-width="3"
           fill="green">
       </circle>
   </svg>
   ```

[Here's a working plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/HCTMsDvpm7J0co5mRjil?p=preview)

Comment: This work thanks. Can you also please help me with multiline uib-tooltip, i tried uib-tooltip-html-unsafe but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="TooltipDemoCtrl">
    <svg>
      <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="50" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="Hellow World">
      </circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TooltipDemoCtrl', function () {
})
```

;

Comment: this code works, but it doesn't utilize the ui-bootstrap tooltip directive

Comment: please check your versions of files- ui-bootstrap. angularjs etc..?. Any error in console? I have created a plunker, working demo. [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/WeIYtnxTcQphVA6eJX82?p=preview)